# How to set Business Key in Spring Boot Activity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bpmn

I am looking for a way to set the Business key of an Activiti process so that it is saved in the execution table as well as in the history table. I found that we can set it during the start of a process instance.

```
ExecutionEntity processInstance= (ExecutionEntity) processEngine.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("abcProcess",*"123456"*,variables);
```

However, it is not being saved during any UserTask while the process is in progress. We are forced to save it manually using a task listener.

Is there any automated way to wiring the business key to a process instance so that it is saved automatically in both the runtime table and the history table?

Answer (score 3):

You have just discovered one of the limitations of Business Key. Once set (usually at process initialization) it will not change unless you explicitly set it in code (such as a listener).

As such, we typically only use business keys for process instance classification (allows us to search based on process type and business key).

Not the answer you wanted, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I know, is old post, just for someone wich this error, try calling this code after start process:

```
@Description("update businessKey")
public void updateBusinessKey(String processInstanceId, String businessKey) {
    try {
        runtimeService.updateBusinessKey(processInstanceId, businessKey);
        System.out.println("SIGMIN-LOG-INFO -> Processo atualizado: " + processInstanceId + "novo Business Key: "
                + businessKey);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of spring you are using, there could be a bug you encounter with version 5.22.0 of Activiti

https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/commit/13ae26eae2656bcbe13a5a2f98f71d9a28898e24

I believe the fix is in 5.23.0, but because I am using Spring Boot which manages the version of Activiti getting pulled in, it is not able to be upgraded as far as I can tell.

The documentation here https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#restProcessInstancesGet

says you should be able to do the following:

```
<callActivity id="callSubProcess" calledElement="checkCreditProcess" activiti:businessKey="${myVariable}">
```